# Finding the intersection of the graphs of two functions algebraically.

Tags: functions

Here is the question:

> Consider the fucntions $f_1 (x) =x$, $f_2 (x) = 2 + ln(x)$. The graphs of the following functions intersect:
>
> 1. once in $(0,1)$ and never in $(1,\infty)$ 2.once in $(0,1)$ and once in $(e^2, \infty)$ 3. once in $(0,1)$ and once in $(e, e^2)$ 4. more than twice in $(0, \infty)$

By drawing the graphs (using a little bit of derivatives to know the shape of $f_2$) we can find the intersections intervals. I'm thinking if we can find the solution of this problem just by algebra (analysis). So, to find the intersections we shall put
$$f_1 = f_2 \\
x = 2 + ln(x) \\
ln (x) = x -2 $$

But I don't know what to do after this.

Comment: $$\ln x=x-2\implies x=e^{x-2}\implies -xe^{-x}=-e^{-2}\implies ye^y=-e^{-2}$$ where $y:=-x$ whose solution is given by $y=W(-e^{-2})$, or $x=-W(-e^{-2})$ where $W(\cdot)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Since $-e^{-1}\leq -e^{-2}\lt 0$, there are two solutions given by the branches $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_2$ is *concave*: any line that intersects its graph can only do so at most twice. Since
$$f_2(1/e^3)<f_1(1/e^3)$$
$$f_2(1)>f_1(1)$$
$$f_2(e)>f_1(e)$$
$$f_2(e^2)<f_1(e^2)$$
there are exactly two solutions, one in $(0,1)$ and one in $(e,e^2)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was a-thinking did we really need the options for solving this question? I mean in your comparisons you used $1/e^3$ and $e^2$, would it have been natural to do if the options were not given? (I'm asking it for myself, I have no doubt on your skills).

Comment: @DeltaPsi If you knew that $f_2$ was concave you would have been able to get my answer without looking at the options.